# Connection scoped temp tables across stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, database-connection, temp-tables

I'm working on a data virtualization solution. The user is able to write his own SQL queries as filters for a query i make. I would like not having to run this filter query every time i select something from the database(It will likely be a complex series of joins).

My idea was to use a # temp table at script level and keep the connection alive. This #temp table would then be selected from  but updated only when the user changes the filter. The idea being i can actually use it from stored procedures and the table is scoped to that connection.

I got the idea from someone who suggested to use dynamic sql and ## global temp tables named with the connection process ID so to make each connection have a unique global temp table. This was to overcome sharing temp tables across stored procedures. But it seems a bit clumsy.

I did a quick test with the below code and seemed to work fine

```
-- Run script at connection open from some app
SELECT * INTO #test
FROM   dataTable

-- Now we can use stored procedures with #test table
EXECUTE selectFromTempTable

EXECUTE updateTempTable @sqlFilterString

EXECUTE selectFromTempTable
```

Only real problem i can see is the connection have to be kept alive for the duration which can be a few hours maybe. A single user can have multiple connections running at the same time. The number of users on a single database server would be like max 20.
If its a huge issue i could make it so the application can close and open them as needed so each user only have 1 connection open at a time. And maybe even then close it if not in use, and reopen when needed again with the delay of having to wait for the query to run.

Would this be bad practice? or kill any performance benefit from not running the filter query? This is on SQL Server 2008 and up.

Comment: You don't have anyway to keep the results of your initial query in your app's memory where the user could continue to filter?

Comment: I might, but it depends on the size of the result the filter query returns. In all honesty your right but you know "owner unwilling to commit to any constraints" so i have to build it so it can make coffee and send emails.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would create a permanent table, using the spid (process ID) as a key value. Each connection has its own process ID, so anyone can use it to identify their entries in the table:

```
create table filter( 
  spid int, 
  filternum int, 
  filterstring varchar(255), 
  <other cols> );
create unique index filterindx on filter(spid, filternum);
```

Then when a user creates filter entries:

```
delete from filter where spid = @@spid
insert into filter(spid, filternum, filterstring) select @@spid, 1, 'some sql thing'
insert into filter(spid, filternum, filterstring) select @@spid, 2, 'some other sql thing'
```

Then you can access each user's filter values by selecting `where spid = @@spid`   etc